# Create 2 group in expandable listview in android

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Hi i have to create 2 groups in my expandable listview android application..but i can't develop this.please help me.
this is my code:

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                R.layout.group_row,             // Group item layout XML.
                new String[] { "OrderInfo","CustomerInfo"},  // the key of group item.
                new int[] { R.id.order,R.id.customer},

                // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.
                createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                R.layout.single_list_item,  
              //  new String[] {"KEY_ARTIST"},  
               // new int[] { R.id.payment_label}  // Keys in childData maps to display.
                  // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
               new String[] {"KEY_ARTIST","KEY_DURATION","KEY_SUBTOTAL","KEY_DISCOUNT","KEY_COUPON","KEY_COST"},  
               new int[] { R.id.payment_label,R.id.total_label,R.id.discount_label,R.id.discount_label,R.id.coupon_label,R.id.cost_label}// Keys in childData maps to display.
             //   new int[] { R.id.payment_label,R.id.total_label}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
            );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );       // setting the adapter in the list.

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/* Creating the Hashmap for the row */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createGroupList() {
      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
      for( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i ) { // 15 groups........
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
       m.put( "OrderInfo","CustomerInfo " + i ); // the key and it's value.


        result.add( m );
      }
      return (List)result;

}
```

here i have to create 2 groups orderinfo and customerinfo..how is create above code..please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct way of creating `Expandable List View`.But there may be something problem. so just go through this [link](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html).

please check that you must extends your activity by `ExpandableListActivity`

and

in layout give id as `android:id="@+id/android:list"` for `ExpandableListView`